# bash - tshark command not recognized when launched from script file

Tags: bash, tshark

I am trying to write a simple bash file able to capture Wi-Fi traffic that looks like this:

```
STRING1="tshark -i 2 -a duration:5 -w <path of output.pcap>"
$STRING1
echo "'Wi-Fi' captured"

STRING2="tshark -r <path of output.pcap> -T fields -e frame.number -E header=y > <path of output.csv>"
echo $STRING2
$STRING2
```

The first command STRING1 is correctly processed and output.pcap is created. When STRING2 is launched i get the error `tshark: Syntax error.`. But if I just copy and paste the STRING2 command in the terminal everything works fine.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it possible that your paths have spaces in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell syntax (redirection operators, pipes, etc) are parsed before word expansion, so your output redirection is being passed as arguments to `tshark`.

```
STRING2="tshark -r <path of output.pcap> -T fields -e frame.number -E header=y"
echo $STRING2
$STRING2 > <path of output.csv>
```

Comment: Definitely a new-by in bash, am I? Thank you chepner!